# Python 3.5.1 - Much needed advice with a year old piece of code

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've been trying to create a turn-based RPG using what meager knowledge of Python I have scince early 2015, but I abandoned the project because of a problem with this piece of code:

```
pattack=""
pnote=""
pdmg=0
ppriority=0

selectmove=int(input("Select move number 1-4"))

if selectmove==1:
    pattack="Fire Ball"
    pdmg=pdmg+150
    ppriority=ppriority+60
    pnote="A firey ball is shot at the enemy"
elif selectmove==2:
    pattack="Thunder Bolt"
    pdmg=pdmg+100
    ppriority=ppriority+80
    pnote="A bolt of electricity is shot at the enemy"
elif selectmove==3:
    pattack="Leaf Wirlwind"
    pdmg=pdmg+175
    ppriority=ppriority+50
    pnote="A Wirlwind of razor sharp leaves is sent to the enemy"
elif selectmove==4:
    pattack="Icicle Shot"
    pdmg=pdmg+75
    ppriority=ppriority+100
    pnote="A sharp icicle is shot at the enemy"
pdmg=int(pdmg)
ppriority=int(ppriority)
print(int("Used the move "+pattack+"\nDealt "+str(pdmg)+" Damage\nHas a priority of "+str(ppriority)+"\nMove description: *NOT FINAL*\n"+pnote+" "))`
```

All I ever get is this error message:

```
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Alberto\Desktop\My Test RPG\Battle System Idea\An Idea I have.py", line 30, in <module>
    print(int("Used the move "+pattack+"\nDealt "+str(pdmg)+" Damage\nHas a priority of "+str(ppriority)+"\nMove description: *NOT FINAL*\n"+pnote+" "))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Used the move Fire Ball\nDealt 150 Damage\nHas a priority of 60\nMove description: *NOT FINAL*\nA firey ball is shot at the enemy "
```

Comment: You're converting the entire string into an integer on the last line. I don't think that's what you intend to do, right?

Comment: What number would you expect `'Used the move Fire Ball\nDealt 150 Damage\nHas a priority of 60\nMove description: *NOT FINAL*\nA firey ball is shot at the enemy "` to be?

Comment: I don't get why you are trying to convert *everything possible* to int. `pdmg=int(pdmg)` when `pdmg` is **already** an `int`.

Answer (score 1):

```
print(int("Used the move "+pattack+"\nDealt "+str(pdmg)+" Damage\nHas a priority of "+str(ppriority)+"\nMove description: *NOT FINAL*\n"+pnote+" "))
```

That line should be:

```
print("Used the move "+pattack+"\nDealt "+str(pdmg)+" Damage\nHas a priority of "+str(ppriority)+"\nMove description: *NOT FINAL*\n"+pnote+" ")
```

You don't want to convert the entire string to `int`.

Answer (score 0):

In your last `print` line, you don't need the `int()` call: it's only used to convert a value into an integer, which that string is not.